# Ansys Mechanical Section Plane Error

Tags: ansys, deformation, meshing

I'm attempting to make a deformation analysis for a specific scenario in Ansys Mechanical. Everything seems to be fine, but when I try to use a section plane, the deformed region appears to be 'hollow,' as shown in the figure regardless of how fine the mesh is
[image: 1]
will appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the mesh solid or shell?

Comment: It is a solid mesh.

Comment: Is the figure you have provided made with section plane? Shouldn't the section at least be straight? It seems more like manually selected element faces (with some omitted).

Comment: This is a section plane view, I was trying to focus on the deformed region so the hollow geometry is clear.

Comment: And did the analysis succeed? I could imagine such behaviour when there is an error like "DOF limit exceeded", where the some results are invalid and the others missing, so the geometry might appear hollow. Could you post a picture of whole Workbench window, so the settings can be seen?